# Difference between using plural pronouns vs singular in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> **From the SAT:**
>
> Psychologists advise that before making any major changes in their lives, people should focus on their goals.

This is the right answer but another choice seems plausible to me but I don't know why it is wrong

> **Here is the other choice:**
>
> Psychologists advise that before making any major changes in their life, a person needs to focus on their goals.

Can someone explain to me why the second sentence is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think the pronouns are a red herring. The issue is with *advise* in conjunction with *should* as opposed to *need* - I suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the thoughtful comment made by Araucaria, considering the source is the SAT, I believe it is simply a matter of **faulty pronoun-antecedent agreement**: **"their lives," "people" and "their goals" are all correctly plural**; while "their life" (who is/are "they"?), "a person" (singular) and "their goals" (back to the plural again) represents a hodge-podge of mismatched words. **A singular antecedent calls for a singular pronoun.** To say, "Psychologists advise that before making any major changes in his or her life, a person needs to focus on his or her goals" is awkward and inelegant, and it is easily fixed by switching to the plural.